# How do I get Laravel's Redirect::away() to honor the protocol specified in the URL?

Tags: php, http, redirect, laravel, https

I have a Laravel 4.0 app running over HTTPS that masks URLS in the customer control panels by routing all remote redirects through a single route. I am using Redirect::away() to handle those redirects but even when the URL string specifies "http", it is redirecting over https. Is there a way for me to enforce the protocol that is specified in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Redirect::to() instead (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.0/src/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.php#L113)

I am assuming you were originally using the away method to route externally so...

Using the Redirect::to(), if you provide a valid protocol (eg. http://) the url generator will simply pass back the specified full url (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.0/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L86) for the redirect to then be made (by createRedirect method).

You only need to set the secure param if you are using relative urls.

EDIT: The implementation slightly differs, but the above information is also valid for laravel 4.1 and 4.2